# MFC connect to sql server with ODBC

Tags: c++, sql-server, mfc, odbc

I have a SDI MFC and I want to use CDatabase to connect to a remote SQL server.

I've created a ODBC connection in my computer, and the DSN is 'TodoTest'.

Here is my code.

```
CDatabase db;
CString connStr = _T("DSN=TodoTest;");
if (!db.OpenEx(connStr, CDatabase::openReadOnly))
{
    // Failed to connect to database.
    return;
}
CRecordset rs(&db);
......
```

The question is it seems OpenEx() has been suspended forever, because I can not see any return value of it, and the code never runs to the subsequent lines.

The program is frozen.

Should I include any other information in the connection string?

Thanks.

Comment: How long did you wait? Enough to run into a timeout? Also note that your connection string is incomplete. It is missing user and password information. Look into the documentation for a sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dhc1abk.aspx#cdatabase__openex

Comment: @erg User and password are not needed, you will type those into ODBC connection dialog. You need to insert them when you use `CDatabase::noOdbcDialog` option.

Comment: That looks fine, try to debug deeper, when on purpose I inserted wrong ODBC name, it throw me expection. Try to check where exactly it stucks. Providing wrong ODBC name goes this way: `CDatabase::OpenEx - > CDatabase::Connect -> CDatabase::ThrowDBException`

Comment: @kajojeq: I do not know the mfc ODBC classes in detail, but I know that the C++ ODBC API always requires a username and a password (at least for Sql Server, MySql and DB2) even if it is configured in the DSN settings. As the MFC classes will probably just wrap around the C++ ODBC API, I doubt that you do not need them when using MFC.

Comment: @erg calling OpenEx without  `cDatabase:noOdbcDialog` will result on showing dialog with authorization, @Eddy don't have that option so dialog will be shown and insert auth to string is not necessary

Comment: @kajojeq: You are right, I didnt read all remarks. Still, connecting to a DSN is not possible without username and password (else no dialog would be required) ;)
But: Maybe you have just identified the problem of Eddy? His call might be blocking, because somewhere a modal dialog is shown, asking for uid and auth, but either the dialog is not visible (no gui app?) or some other reason. Still for simplicty I would try to use a connection string similar to the one shown in the sample - one including uid and pw.

Comment: @erg I did tests, all works fine. When you give wrong string it just throw you exception. Couldn't reapeat problem, You may be right with that gui thing

Comment: @erg: Yes I guess the UI is somehow blocked, because I waited for a long time and there was no any timeout message. But after I changed the ODBC driver to 32bit, it looked fine. The problem seemed to reside in the dialog. I cannot still come up with why...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to everybody!

Finally get the point!

It's seems that my application don't accept the 64bit ODBC driver, so I go to `%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64` to find the 32bit ODBC manager.

Then I create a 32bit ODBC source again and it works well !!

Comment: Thanks to kajojeq, I tried deeper debug and found it was because something about ODBC driver.

You gave the inspiration to me.